# Schedule Auto Re-Boot of Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: script, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there any specific command or script through which I can schedule an Auto reboot of Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly the [shutdown](http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html) command from a Command Prompt?

```
shutdown -r -f -t 10
```

Where:

- *-r* restarts
- *-f* forces processes to terminate
- *-t 10* waits 10 seconds before shutdown

The way I would do this is by scheduling a batch file with the above line in it, although you will probably be able to do this through PowerShell too.

Comment: Exactly how we used to do it.

Comment: @Joe Taylor: *used* to do it?

Comment: thanx for the help !

Comment: Yeah, I no longer work for that company so no longer have to reboot their servers. I'm sure they still do it that way. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Command Prompt, type:

```
AT 06:00 SHUTDOWN -r -f
```

At 6:00am the Server or PC will Reboot (`-r`) and any running apps will be exited (`-f`)

This command creates a Scheduled Task.

Now How easy is that?

You can get really funky on the Comand line by scheduling a reboot every weekday at a specific time.